# Is there a way I can return a promise from a $resource without needing to use $q?

Tags: angularjs

I have coded the following service:

```
angular.module('App')
    .factory('TestService', ['$http', '$q', '$resource', function (
                          $http, $q, $resource) {

        var TestResource = $resource('/api/Tests', {}, {
            saveData: { method: 'PUT' },
            deleteData: { method: "DELETE", params: { TestId: 0 } }
        });

        var factory = {

            query: function (selectedSubject) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                TestResource.query({ subjectId: selectedSubject },
                   function (resp) {
                       deferred.resolve(resp);
                   }
                );
                return deferred.promise;

                //return Test.query({ subjectId: selectedSubject });
            }

        }
        return factory;
}]);
```

In my controller I am calling it this way:

```
TestService.query($scope.selectedSubject)
                        .then(function (result) {
                            $scope.gridData = result;
                        }, function (result) {
                            alert("Error: No data returned");
                        });
```

Is there a way that I could cut out a few lines of code by not having $q in my service. Is there a way that I could return a promise from the $resource? I have tried the commented out code but that gives me an error saying there is no ".then" method.

Comment: study step 11 of tutorial on docs site... it answers your question http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11. If you haven't downloaded the tutorial and gone through each step it is well worth the time spent

Comment: Why is it not efficient for you to have $q in your service?

Comment: I am okay with having $q in the service. I was just wondering if I could simplify the code by returning a promise without needing to use $q. I changed my question to make it a bit more clear. Thanks

Comment: @charlietfl This could easily transformed into a accepted answer.

Comment: @TheHippo - I am not sure if that's correct. The step 11 returns an object with methods if I am reading it correctly.

Comment: you code returns a promise only for query method? Do I need to add a new function for the others to return promises?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$resource can't return a promise in the current stable version of Angular (1.0.8), but it looks like it'll come in version 1.2. [It was added in v1.1.3](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-1) (v 1.1 is the unstable branch):

> **$resource**: expose promise based api via $then and $resolved ([dba6bc73](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dba6bc73e802fdae685a9f351d3e23c7efa8568a))